# SuiteCRM Issue with Time

Tags: mysql, time, suitecrm

SuiteCRM
I am facing time issue in SuiteCRM. In SuiteCRM created date is not same as in database. Similarly in report and schedule.
I have change timezone in following file/setting:

- php.ini
- the system date format in Admin / Locale
- the relevant user profile sections in each user’s profile.
  But issue is still exist.

[image: cr]

Answer (score 1):

SuiteCRM stores the dates in MySQL using the UTC timezone GMT-0.

So regardless of your setting, you will always have the Date represented in GMT-0.

This is by design so it's easier to render dates for users in different timezones.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $current_user;
 
$timeDate = new TimeDate($current_user);

$datetime = "2019/08/01 13:00" ;//eg. +5:30 (india) , current user format is "Y/m/d H:i"
                                        
$timeDate->asDb($datetime); // "2019-08-01 09:00:00" (UTC)
```